Swiper SlideToClickedSlide not show loop correctly
I'm working with React and Swiper to show a slide of products, but I have the following problem:
When I click in the first and the last element of the slide, it does not show the previews or next elements and it leaves blank space. I show some
This is the initial state of the slide
enter image description here
When the user click in the last element, the next elements are not show as you can see below
enter image description here
And when I drag a little the last element, the next slides appear as you can see below
enter image description here
This is my swiper configuration, but I'm stuck with that problem This is my code, but I'm stuck with that problem. can anyone help me?
/* eslint-disable react/forbid-dom-props */
/* eslint-disable react/function-component-definition */
import clsx from 'clsx';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { EffectCoverflow } from 'swiper/modules';
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/react';

import 'swiper/css';
import 'swiper/css/effect-coverflow';
import 'swiper/css/pagination';

import FeatureDemo from './FeatureDemo';

import Image3 from '../assets/camera.png'; // Kit élastiques de musculation
import Image5 from '../assets/charging-packback.jpg'; // Sac à dos de voyage antivol
import Image1 from '../assets/hismile.png'; // Dentifrice correcteur de couleur
import Image2 from '../assets/kit-bande.jpg'; // Caméra de surveillance
import Image6 from '../assets/revitalift-500.jpg'; // Revitalift, crème anti-âge
import Image4 from '../assets/smart-watch.jpg'; // Montre connectée

interface ProductProps {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  description: string;
  anglesmarketing: string;
  objections: string;
  email1: string;
  email2: string;
  email3: string;
  faq: string;
  briefinflu: string;
}

interface SlideProductsProps {
  products: ProductProps[];
}

const SlideProducts: React.FC<SlideProductsProps> = ({ products }) => {
  const [activeSlideIndex, setActiveSlideIndex] = useState(0);
  const [selectedProduct, setSelectedProduct] = useState<ProductProps | null>();

  const handleSlideChange = (index: number) => {
    console.log(`swiper.realIndex = ${index}`);
    setActiveSlideIndex(index);
    setSelectedProduct(products[index]);
  };

  const getImage = (id: number) => {
    switch (id) {
      case 0:
        return Image1;
      case 1:
        return Image3;
      case 2:
        return Image2;
      case 3:
        return Image4;
      case 4:
        return Image5;
      case 5:
        return Image6;
      default:
        return Image1;
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Swiper
        effect="coverflow"
        grabCursor
        centeredSlides
        slideToClickedSlide
        loop
        slidesPerView="auto"
        coverflowEffect={{
          rotate: 0,
          stretch: 8,
          depth: 180,
          modifier: 1,
          slideShadows: false,
          scale: 1,
        }}
        modules={[EffectCoverflow]}
        className="xl:w-[1300px] lg:w-[970px] xs:w-[350px] 3xs:w-[380px] 4xs:w-[460px] sm:w-[620px] md:w-[715px] py-[50px] mt-10 xs:border-red-500 sm:border-yellow-500 md:border-blue-500 lg:border-green-500 xl:border-cyan-500"
        onTransitionEnd={(swiper: { realIndex: number }) =>
          handleSlideChange(swiper.realIndex)
        }
      >
        {products.map(({ id }, index) => (
          <SwiperSlide
            key={id}
            className="py-1 xs:!w-[99px] 3xs:!w-[108px] 4xs:!w-[128px] sm:!w-[169px] md:!w-[193px] lg:!w-[257px] xl:!w-[342px] text-center"
          >
            <svg
              style={{
                background: `url(${getImage(index)})`,
                backgroundColor: 'white',
                backgroundSize: 'cover',
                backgroundPosition: 'center',
              }}
              className={clsx(
                `xs:!w-[80px] xs:h-[120px] 3xs:!w-[85px] 4xs:!w-[103px] 4xs:h-[135px] sm:!w-[140px] sm:h-[200px] md:!w-[160px] md:h-[230px] lg:!w-[210px] lg:h-[260px] xl:!w-[290px] xl:h-[350px] object-contain rounded-[10px] bg-white`,
                index === activeSlideIndex &&
                  'border-solid md:border-2 lg:border-3 xs:border-1 border-[#8729C1] bg-white'
              )}
            />
          </SwiperSlide>
        ))}
      </Swiper>
      {selectedProduct && <FeatureDemo product={selectedProduct} />}
    </>
  );
};

export default SlideProducts;

